# How to process formula object to a character object?

Tags: r, string

Here is my question:

```
formula = label ~ m1 + m2 + m2m1 + topix + sp500 + Open + High + Low +
  Close + Volume + psyco12 + psyco24 + closeB5 + closeB10 +
  closeB20 + closeB60 + William5 + William8 + William13 + William21 +
  William34 + RSV9 + K + D + KD + MA5 + MA10 + MA20 + MA60 +
  MA120 + MA240 + MA5MA20 + DI + EMA12 + EMA26 + DIF + MACD +
  OSC + change + RSI6p + RSI6m + RSI6 + RSI12p + RSI12m + RSI12 +
  RSI6RSI12 + OBV + JPYUSD + MarCap + MonthVol + MonthVal +
  GV
```

class(formula) is formula

i want to convert it to the following format.

```
c("m1","m2","m2m1","topix","sp500","Open","High","Low",
                 "Close","Volume","psyco12","psyco24","closeB5","closeB10", 
                 "closeB20","closeB60","William5","William8","William13","William21",
                 "William34","RSV9","K","D","KD","MA5","MA10","MA20","MA60",
                 "MA120","MA240","MA5MA20","DI","EMA12","EMA26","DIF","MACD",
                 "OSC","change","RSI6p","RSI6m","RSI6","RSI12p","RSI12m","RSI12", 
                 "RSI6RSI12","OBV","JPYUSD","MarCap","MonthVol","MonthVal","GV")
```

including that c()

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option would be `reformulate` to convert from `vector` of names to formula

```
f1 <- reformulate(v1, "label")
```

---

And for reverse, use the `all.vars`

```
v2 <- all.vars(f1)[-1]
dput(v2)
c("m1", "m2", "m2m1", "topix", "sp500", "Open", "High", "Low", 
"Close", "Volume", "psyco12", "psyco24", "closeB5", "closeB10", 
"closeB20", "closeB60", "William5", "William8", "William13", 
"William21", "William34", "RSV9", "K", "D", "KD", "MA5", "MA10", 
"MA20", "MA60", "MA120", "MA240", "MA5MA20", "DI", "EMA12", "EMA26", 
"DIF", "MACD", "OSC", "change", "RSI6p", "RSI6m", "RSI6", "RSI12p", 
"RSI12m", "RSI12", "RSI6RSI12", "OBV", "JPYUSD", "MarCap", "MonthVol", 
"MonthVal", "GV")
```

Or if there are multiple dependent variables,

```
all.vars(as.list(f1)[[3]])
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("m1","m2","m2m1","topix","sp500","Open","High","Low",
                 "Close","Volume","psyco12","psyco24","closeB5","closeB10", 
                 "closeB20","closeB60","William5","William8","William13","William21",
                 "William34","RSV9","K","D","KD","MA5","MA10","MA20","MA60",
                 "MA120","MA240","MA5MA20","DI","EMA12","EMA26","DIF","MACD",
                 "OSC","change","RSI6p","RSI6m","RSI6","RSI12p","RSI12m","RSI12", 
                 "RSI6RSI12","OBV","JPYUSD","MarCap","MonthVol","MonthVal","GV")
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another option using @akrun's data (`v1`). Following the documentation on [formula](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.0/topics/formula), you can get the variables using:

```
attr(terms.formula(formula), "term.labels")
# output
 [1] "m1"        "m2"        "m2m1"      "topix"     "sp500"    
 [6] "Open"      "High"      "Low"       "Close"     "Volume"   
[11] "psyco12"   "psyco24"   "closeB5"   "closeB10"  "closeB20" 
[16] "closeB60"  "William5"  "William8"  "William13" "William21"
[21] "William34" "RSV9"      "K"         "D"         "KD"       
[26] "MA5"       "MA10"      "MA20"      "MA60"      "MA120"    
[31] "MA240"     "MA5MA20"   "DI"        "EMA12"     "EMA26"    
[36] "DIF"       "MACD"      "OSC"       "change"    "RSI6p"    
[41] "RSI6m"     "RSI6"      "RSI12p"    "RSI12m"    "RSI12"    
[46] "RSI6RSI12" "OBV"       "JPYUSD"    "MarCap"    "MonthVol" 
[51] "MonthVal"  "GV"
```

Now, you just have to apply `dput()` to the above object to include the `c()`:

```
dput(attr(terms.formula(formula), "term.labels"))
# output
c("m1", "m2", "m2m1", "topix", "sp500", "Open", "High", "Low", 
"Close", "Volume", "psyco12", "psyco24", "closeB5", "closeB10", 
"closeB20", "closeB60", "William5", "William8", "William13", 
"William21", "William34", "RSV9", "K", "D", "KD", "MA5", "MA10", 
"MA20", "MA60", "MA120", "MA240", "MA5MA20", "DI", "EMA12", "EMA26", 
"DIF", "MACD", "OSC", "change", "RSI6p", "RSI6m", "RSI6", "RSI12p", 
"RSI12m", "RSI12", "RSI6RSI12", "OBV", "JPYUSD", "MarCap", "MonthVol", 
"MonthVal", "GV")
```

*Definition of formula:*

```
formula <- as.formula(paste("label ~ ", paste(v1, collapse = " + "), sep = ""))
```